# Odd Exception from Facebook: JavaScript runtime error: CSS component nnnn has already been requested

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk, windows-runtime

I have a Facebook application on Windows Runtime that uses the Facebook C-Sharp SDK.

When logging in for the first time, the normal sequence of operation commence; login, accept permissions, name the device, and I'm in.
All good.

I continue to develop my app, starting it, logging in using the FacebookClient object, debugging back and forth with my business logic.
Then right out of the blue, after my token (normally) has expired, and I'm forced to re-logon, I get the Exception after entering my credentials in the Facebook login page:

> Unhandled exception at line 30, column 1719 in
>   https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yr/r/gz5FaFUp24x.js
>   0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: CSS component A7UAf has already
>   been requested.

An unhandled Exception dialog is shown , I have to select how to debug.
When swithcing back to my app, the web browser content is displaying the prompt to name my device:

> Name New Device Please give this device a name. Because you have Login
>   Notifications enabled, you will receive a notification that you

(Yes, it's cut out)

And then re-directed to a page saying:

> Review Recent Login.
>
> Someone recently tried to log in to your account from an unrecognized
>   device or mobile device. Because you enabled login notifications, your
>   account is temporarily locked.
>
> Please complete the following steps to regain access to your account.

I then have to logon with a normal web browser, where I have new message saying that I have to acknowledge the "suspicious" logon and name the device.
After that, everything works for a couple of hours or even a day, then the same thing happens again.

What's going on?